# How to initialize an instance of IVectorView for C++/WRL?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-10, wrl

I'm trying to call `get_Skus()` method of `IStoreProduct` to retrieve its [Skus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.services.store.storeproduct.skus.aspx) property using [C++/WRL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466.aspx) (not C++/CX) and I can't find any suitable code examples. That method is defined as such (as I get it from the header file in Visual Studio):

```
virtual /* [propget] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_Skus( 
        /* [out][retval] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IVectorView<ABI::Windows::Services::Store::StoreSku*> **value) = 0;
```

So when I try to do:

```
#include <Windows.Services.Store.h>
#include <wrl.h>

using namespace ABI::Windows::Services::Store;
using namespace ABI::Windows::Foundation::Collections;

IVectorView<StoreSku*> pStrSkus;

//IStoreProduct* pStorePrdct = ...;
if (SUCCEEDED(pStorePrdct->get_Skus(&pStrSkus)))
{
}
```

it gives me an error that:

> 'ABI::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView'
>   : cannot instantiate abstract class

I'm relatively new to `WRL`. Can someone show me how am I supposed to call that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a star - it should have been this:

```
IVectorView<StoreSku*>* pStrSkus;

if (SUCCEEDED(pStorePrdct->get_Skus(&pStrSkus)))
{
    ...
    pStrSkus->Release();
}
```

Even better, use a ComPtr instead, so you don't have to release it manually:

```
ComPtr<IVectorView<StoreSku*>> pStrSkus;

if (SUCCEEDED(pStorePrdct->get_Skus(&pStrSkus)))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was easy.

Comment: Listen, it's a separate question, but if I need to initiate and pass an `IVector` of `HSTRING`s how would I do it? Pretty much this in C# converted to C++/WRL: `string[] storeIds = new string[] { "9NBLGGH4TNMP", "9NBLGGH4TNMN" };`

Comment: You need to make a class that implements IVector<HSTRING>. Easiest to do by wrapping std::vector<Microsoft:WRL::HString>.